In apache http client(spring boot) we have a configuration connectionRequestTimeout, is there a way to test or see if this setting is working
How to test connectionRequestTimeout in apache http client, want to know what if exceeds the set milliseconds.
I am unable to test whether this setting is working nor I am able to find if we have exceeded this set time.
Also does this setting make sure we get a connection from the connection pool with in the said time please.
